# How to perform some action every time computer with Windows starts?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, automation

I'd like to perform some task (start a program) on a computer running Windows every time it's (re)started. It's remote computer and just placing shortcut in autostart doesn't work because it's run every time I log into using remote desktop.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Windows Task Scheduler. It's been a while since I used it on XP, but in Vista and Windows 7 you can schedule a task to occur on startup. This can be a batch file, or executable.

Comment: This is available in XP as well

Comment: I wasn't too sure if this option was in XP. Thanks.

Comment: In XP it's called Scheduled Tasks, not Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to running an application as a service. If the application supports it you can look at using [Service Any](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890). This will start the application when the machine boots without needing to login.

However be aware that most applications don't work with it, unless they are service type daemons already.

Comment: I just want to send email from command line (batch file) using BLAT. This does not sound like a service at all :)

Comment: Then the Task Scheduler is a better option

Comment: Your answer is still interesting as once I was looking for exactly what you are describing :) +1