# How to auto start a program when booting in windows?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to perform some action every time computer with Windows starts?](https://superuser.com/questions/34811/how-to-perform-some-action-every-time-computer-with-windows-starts)

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to put the app in your startup folder.

This is a little old, but it explains your options very well, and it still applies to the latest Windows offerings.

http://www.aumha.org/a/loads.php

Comment: +1, or even in the registry

Comment: +1, start up folder is the best place, because it's easy for the user to find and remove if they don't want the program there. I hate having to go through the registry/msconfig to find programs that think they're **so totally awesome** that I just can't live without them running *all the time*.

Comment: I agree with @Dean but there are times, with company pc's, that the registry is a requirement so that the user cannot remove the app.  Again, I think the OP has left a lot of detail out of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little cryptic as to the exact reason of why but;

Have you looked into Windows Kiosk Mode?

http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-setup-windows-vista-and-7-as-a-kiosk/
http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/windows-xp/8239-windows-xp-kiosk-mode.html