# How to load my program when Windows starts without a command console appears?

Tags: windows, command-line, boot

I want to start my application, which is written in C# and has `.exe` files, when installed at the beginning of Windows loading.

I would like to load it into into the application if possible.

I don't want the user to see anything after the Windows logo screen. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform some action every time computer with Windows starts?](http://superuser.com/questions/34811/how-to-perform-some-action-every-time-computer-with-windows-starts)

Comment: So you want to just start an application? Or do you actually want to load something *into* your application, which you programmed yourself? It's not that clear from your question what you really want to do

Comment: As I understand the question, denonth wants to start his "cmd" based app with Windows without "cmd" shows itself when starting the .exe file.... This is not the same as the cited duplication asks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mainly, you need to add your .exe or the method used to start the exe to your autorun registry key(to make your Windows start the program automatically):

1. You could use your Windows Task Scheduler. Just type scheduler on your Windows search, open the Windows Task Scheduler and create a task with the "start with Windows" trigger to start your exe with Windows.
2. You could just add your executable command to [the Windows Registry autorun key:](http://www.ehow.com/how_5910614_edit-programs-autostart-registry.html)

> 1. Launch the Registry Editor. This can be done by selecting the "Run"
>      command from the "Start" menu in Windows, then typing "Regedit" into
>      the text box and tapping the "Enter" key. You may also simply type
>      "Regedit" from a CMD or command prompt.
> 2. Open the Local Machine hive. The Registry Editor is arranged
>      hierarchically, like the directory structure you see in the File
>      Manager. At the top-most level there are five sections. Clicking the
>      "+" sign next to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" will expand, or open up, that
>      hive.
> 3. Navigate to the "Run" branch. Clicking the "+" sign next to each
>      item in turn, open up "Software" > "Microsoft" > "Windows." Inside the
>      Windows branch open "CurrentVersion" followed by "Run."
> 4. Preserve the current settings. Right-click on the word "Run" in the
>      left panel of the Registry Editor and select "Export." Ensure the
>      registry path at the bottom is accurate and ends in "\Run." Select the
>      radio button marked "Selected branch" at the bottom-left of the export
>      window. Take note of where you saved this file.
> 5. Add, remove, or alter entries as you see fit. Beware that many
>      ordinary and necessary programs are listed here, blended in with
>      programs you may not need and may not have known you were running.
> 6. When you have made your changes, choose "Save" from the "File" menu
>      at the top-left of the Registry Editor. Quit the Registry Editor and
>      reboot your system.

But if you "want the user to see anything after the Windows logo screen", I can see two main ways:

- Use [HSTART Software with the "NOCONSOLE" argument:](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html)

[image]

- As described on [another reference here on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/191199/79358), you could just add the folowing command to the registry autostart key to start it silently:

> start "" "C:\Your_Program_Path\Your_Program.exe"

Comment: Just what I needed

Comment: I followed the instructions in the 2nd option and it's not working :( My command is `node.exe C:/path/to/my_script.js > C:/path/to/log.txt` and I cannot see the log being created. I know the command works on a cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Search the "Startup" folder then put your program in it. Any program in this folder will start when you start Windows.