# How to boot directly into an application

Tags: windows, boot

I have an application that I want to boot in directly when windows xp starts. So after that "welcome" screen I don't want to see anything and load directly into the app.

How can I do that?

I tried adding a exe file to startup folder. But he is loading some 2-3 thing and then my app and I see windows desktop normally.

Is it possible to load it directly?

It is a windows form application not an cmd.

Comment: Can you clarify the "But he is loading some 2-3 thing and then my app and I see windows desktop normally" part?

Comment: I believe the OP means that 2-3 applications are loading before their app loads when the computer boots. They want just that one app to be the only thing visible when booting.

Comment: Yes that's correct Huskehn. I am loading a 2-3 application at boot time. and some thing are necessary to boot. But I want to boot directly to my app and then other app can boot after that.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for "Kiosk" mode.

Comment: @techie007 yes I need that but difference is that I need it for my program and not for browsers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load my program when Windows starts without a command console appears?](http://superuser.com/questions/435229/how-to-load-my-program-when-windows-starts-without-a-command-console-appears) – what is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Note**: This will replace the whole Windows shell with your application. There will be no start menu, no task bar and no desktop.
>
> One way to get it back, is to invoke Task Manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> and start `explorer.exe` from there.
>
> To permanently reverse this change, just start `regedit.exe` again and change the `Shell` key back to `explorer.exe`.

---

### How to fully replace the Windows shell with another application

You can change the registry key

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

to point to your application. Then it will be started instead of `explorer.exe` as the shell.

[image]

Comment: Can I be using a teaviewer in the background?

Comment: If I will have some problem so I can connect to it?

Comment: @denonth: If TeamViewer is started as a service, yes, that may work. I don't know if the *regular* startup items are processed if `explorer.exe` doesn't run.

Comment: this is sort of kiosk mode? Have you tested this? are you sure I can go back if I try this on pc?

Comment: @denonth: Yes, I have made use of this on many occasions. We also regularly use this when we deploy computers at fairs, so they don't look too *windowsy* when they boot. And switching between shells has never been an issue for us.

Comment: so mobile internet, and all other things can be made behind that shell? I mean everything needs to be on automatic mode to be executed?

Comment: so where does my app needs to be installed in order to be called like explorer.exe? Do I need to put the whole path inside or?

Comment: @denonth: It's best to provide an absolute path to your executable.